# How to perform pin pairing ble connection in react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE enabled device which has pin pairing. Which library to use or which is the way using React Native and should work in android as well as ios.

I have tried library ble manager.

Answer (score -1):

The pairing process is generally handled by the operating system, so you should not need to do anything in the application.